# MakeNSIS: Can't install on Windows and on PyCharm

Tags: installation, terminal, pip, nsis

PyCharm
`pip3 install nsis` / `pip3 install makensis` -> `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nsis (from versions: none)`
`pip3 install makensis`

Windows

Is it even possible to install it on Windows or Pycharm Windows ?

Comment: There are no such packages at PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/nsis/, https://pypi.org/project/makensis/. What are you trying to install? Do you mean [`pynsist`](https://pypi.org/project/pynsist/)?

Comment: I want to create an `.exe installer` based on a `.nsi` and an `.exe`. I know how to do it manually with "HM NIS Edit" but I want to make it in command line to automate the process. I'm trying to find the library or whatever stuff that can help me do that. :p

Comment: Well, certainly not with `pip`/PyPI.

Answer (score 1):

`pip` is a package manager for Python libraries. If you want to install NSIS on Windows, you have several options:

- [WinGet](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli): `winget install NSIS.NSIS`
- [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/): `scoop install nsis`
- [Chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/nsis): `choco install nsis`

Other than that, NSIS can be installed using the [official installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/).